# How to make icons for Splash Screen of Progressive Web App available while developing on localhost

Tags: javascript, manifest, splash-screen, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am changing an existing Web Application to a Progressive Web App. Most of it went fine and I'm done now. However, while developing I noticed something odd.

**MY PROGRESS:**

I created the Serviceworker to cache some files, everything went fine. After that, I created the manifest and tried to debug on my Android-Device to test the "Add To Homescreen" Functionality as described [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/add-to-home-screen/#4). That also went mostly fine. I was able to trigger the install and the icon got added, no errors.

**THE PROBLEM:**

However, when starting the PWA, there was no splash screen and it was just opened in Chrome, even though my manifest stated standalone. Name, background_color and icons were given as stated [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/custom-splash-screen). So there had to be something wrong with the icons itself. I also double checked the filenames and made sure that the path was relative to the manifest, cleared the Cache, reinstalled the service worker etc.

**MY RESEARCH:**

What I found was, that in the Developers Tools under Application/Manifest, the icons were displayed when opening the page on my laptop. As soon as I opened the page on my mobile device and inspected the page, there was just the broken file icon shown for both entries. Everything else was matching the manifest.

After that, I hosted the application on Firebase. This time, everything was working fine on desktop and mobile, the splash screen appeared, the app opened as standalone.

So there must be something not working with the PWA trying to catch the icon from localhost:5000/img/app-icon-512.png during installation process. However, accessing that file from the mobile browser worked. Furthermore, there was an icon showing up in the message to install the PWA and on the homescreen. I think this might be the smaller one (192px).

Further Notes:

- Of course I made sure that the phone was still connected to the laptop while installing and opening the PWA.
- I tried caching the icon-files.
- I changed the icon files and took some from the tutorial of the *Building Progressive Web Apps* Book by Tal Ater [GitHub](https://github.com/TalAter/gotham_imperial_hotel) (I think they are in the branch for chapter 10) to make sure the ones I had weren't just too bad quality

**MY QUESTION:**

So, I was curious if someone else got the problem, knows a solution to this or can simply explain the process that installs the PWA on the device and why it cannot access the icon files if they are on localhost with port mapping. It would be nice to be able to test the splash screen simply on localhost.

**manifest.json**:

```
{
  "short_name": "MyApp",
  "name": "Still MyApp",
  "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
  "start_url": "/",
  "scope": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "img/app-icon-192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/app-icon-512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "theme_color": "#0069b2",
  "background_color": "#0069b2"
}
```

**structure**

```
- web
  - some files (index etc.) and folders (js/css etc.)
  - img
    - app-icon-512.png
    - app-icon-192.png
  - manifest.json
  - serviceworker.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that it's working on your laptop and when it's hosted on Firebase. The issue I'm seeing here is that the image cannot be read from your phone because the image is stored in your laptop, not in your phone. What I can suggest is that you instead test on your laptop browser and [Toggle Device Toolbar](https://www.atlantic.net/cloud-hosting/how-to-test-responsive-design-device-mode-chrome-developer-tools/). By using Device Toolbar testing, you can simulate how your PWA looks on different mobile screen sizes - a lot better than testing on your singular phone.

Comment: in all of your dev experience, have you ever made a LOCALHOST program run outside of the laptop/computer that hosts it? (without using internet)

Comment: "The issue [..] is that the image [..] is stored in your laptop, not in your phone."

Yes, that is what I made out as the problem. When using this method, you can only access the laptop as localhost from chrome and, as it seems, not from the initiation process of the 'Add to Homescreen' functionality of a PWA.

The 'Toggle Device Toolbar' however is not a solution because it is not an emulation of a phone but simply resizing the window to mobile size. What I wanted, as stated in the question, is to test the 'Add to Homescreen' functionality efficiently.

Comment: "in all of your dev experience, have you ever made a LOCALHOST program run outside of the laptop/computer that hosts it? (without using internet)". In this case, yes. Of course it is not the standard case, I get your point, you're right there, but as you see, Google gave the opportunity to test the functionality of your PWA on your phone by accessing it via localhost. I was just curious, if this was thought to the end and there is maybe some workaround or if the wanted workflow is to test some features on localhost and the 'Add to Homescreen'-functionality by hosting it.